# What causes the gap in shadows underneath an object?

Tags: rendering, lighting, shadows

In the following render:
[image: final render]

You can see that the shadow of the pink plate on the table isn't complete, as if it is somehow lit. However, if I lift the plate substantially off the table, this problem goes away. I was wondering what causes this? Everything in the scene, except the plate, has no materials assigned, and my lighting setup is the standard one at boot up:

[image: lighting setup]

That's a point light. And the mesh of the plate looks like this:
[image: mesh of plate]

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling contact shadows;

[image]

You may also need to adjust the bias settings (also pictured)